# Is this method based on Wilson score intervals a valid method of calculating the error on the area under a precision-recall curve?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, precision-recall

Suppose I have a set of continuous prediction score. I vary my decision threshold to produce a set of precision and recall scores, which I denote as `P` and `R` respectively.

For each precision score, I calculate an upper and lower confidence interval with the Wilson method. This is the range in which the "true" precision should fall, given we estimate it from a finite number of true and false positives. The same is done for the recall.

I let `A(P,R)` be my estimate of the area under the curve. i.e. the integral of `P` against `R`.

I let `P_u1` be `P`, but with the first precision score replaced with its upper confidence interval and the rest left constant. Similarly, `P_u2` has its second score replaced with the upper confidence interval, and the rest left constant. `P_l1`, `P_l2` is the same for lower boundaries.

I then use the formula for composing independent errors. i.e. I find

```
sqrt(
    [A(P_u1, R)-A(P,R)]**2 +
    [A(P_u2, R)-A(P,R)]**2 + ... +
    [A(P, R_u1)-A(P,R)]**2 +
    [A(P, R_u2)-A(P,R)]**2 + ... +
)
```

as the estimate for the upper error of `A`.

I am not sure if this is quite right, since it seems that `P_u1` and `P_u2` are not independent. However, I have not been able to find any other ways of estimating the error on this.

Comment: +1 for thinking through this (and welcome to CV.SE) Why over-engineer this? What is wrong with doing (say) a repeated CV with 5 repeated of 5-fold have 25 PR-curves and then simply show what is the variance of those 25 PR curves? As you correctly recognise, you have correlated samples when using a single PR curve (Issue 1). In addition, it can be argued that your variance should be a *function* rather than single point estimate (Issue 2). Your method starts with the upper and lower CI based on Wilson but that does not accounts for your classifier's performance variability. (Issue 3)